# The set of invertible linear maps is an open subset of $\mathcal B (V,V)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal B(V,V)$ be the space of continuous (or bounded) linear maps from $V$ to itself, with the operator norm.

I am trying to prove that the set of invertible linear maps is an open subset of $\mathcal B (V,V)$.

I have proved that if a map $\phi$ satisfies $\| \phi \| < 1$ then $I - \phi$ is invertible. I am not sure how this helps me though. Could I have a hint?

Comment: Sometimes it is helpful to rephrase what you actually want to achieve. If $\phi$ is invertible, then you would like to find an $r>0$ (possibly depending on $\phi$), such that every element of the ball of radius $r>0$, centered at $\phi$ in $\mathcal{B}(V)$ is invertible as well. What have you tried from here? How is you observation related to the initial question? Is $V$ a complete space?

Comment: $\|B-A\|<\frac 1{\|A^{-1}\|}$ implies $\|A^{-1}B-I\|<1$ so $A^{-1}B $ is invertible and so is $B$. BTW, this is a duplicate.

Comment: which question is it a duplicate of?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how did you come up with that?